# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '800')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I start my application, I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '800')".

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Menu, MenuItem, Avatar, Box, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material';
import MainTheme, { customColors } from '@/styles/themes/mainTheme';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';

export const HeaderProfileButton = () => {
  
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(true);

  const handleClickClose = () => {
    isOpened ? setIsOpened(false) : setIsOpened(true);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={MainTheme}>
        <Button onClick={handleClickClose} sx={{display: 'flex'}}>
            <AccountCircleIcon sx={{height: '60px', width: '60px', color: customColors.text}}></AccountCircleIcon>
        </Button>
        <Menu open={isOpened} sx={{backgroundColor: customColors.darkBackground, height: '120px', width: '150px', position: 'absolute'}}>
        </Menu>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

This code is for a component that shows a profile button in the header and, on click, should display a little menu. I tried using a similar component from the MUI documentation, but that gave me the same error with 'active' instead of '800'. I have already tried clearing my cache, but I am still unsure of how to resolve this issue.
[image: The error screenshot]

This is my theme that im using:

```
import NextLink from 'next/link';
import { ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

const LinkBehaviour = forwardRef(function LinkBehaviour(props, ref) {
  //@ts-ignore 
  return <NextLink ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
// main color
const primaryColor = '#116466';
const lightPrimaryColor = '#2B7E80';
const darkPrimaryColor = '#004B4D';
// secondary color
const secondaryColor = '#FFB57C';
const lightSecondaryColor = '#FFFFFF';
const darkSecondaryColor = '#000000';
// custom colors
export const customColors = {
  black: '#000000',
  white: '#FFFFFF',
  error: '#F84F31',
  success: '#23C552',
  text: '#D1E8E2',
  darkBackground: '#2C3531',
  lightBackground: '#E4E4E4'
}

export const breakpoints = {
  xLarge: '1500px',
  Large: '1280px',
  Medium: '960px',
  Small: '640px',
  Tiny: '480px'
}

export const generalVariables = {
  contentPadding: '0px 140px'
}

const mainTheme: ThemeOptions = {
  palette: {
    grey: {
      800: '#555555',
    },
    primary: {
      main: primaryColor,
      light: lightPrimaryColor,
      dark: darkPrimaryColor
    },
    secondary: {
      main: secondaryColor,
      light: lightSecondaryColor,
      dark: darkSecondaryColor
    },

  },
};

export default mainTheme;
```

Now the callstack points here:

ButtonRoot.ownerState.ownerState
node_modules@mui\material\Button\Button.js (75:137)

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: You need to narrow down where the error is actually coming from and post that code. Sounds like a MUI issue, but hard to say

Comment: It doesnt says which line exactly, the error just pops up and nothing else

Comment: "the error just pops up" like an alert? If it's in the console, it'll point you to where the error is coming from.

Comment: I added screenshot thats everything i see from the error, it doesnt point me to any line

Comment: @TT Show `MainTheme` - it needs to be the result of a function call to [`createTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/)

Comment: The callstack seems to point to Button.js line 64.

Comment: @mykaf - it's [this line](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L80) which just means that the theme being passed to the `ThemeProvider` isn't correct

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

It's coming from this line: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L80

All this means is that your Theme that you're passing to `ThemeProvider` isn't correct. This bug is because of something gone wrong with `MainTheme`.

---

I'll put this as an answer because I'll bet this is it.

`MainTheme` needs to be the result of a call to [`createTheme`](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/).

And, in your code, it also needs to be the default export from that file.

If it's not, then MUI components (like `Button`) will be trying to access properties on the theme that don't exist - and you'll get those errors

Comment: Here: 
const mainTheme = createTheme(mainThemeOptions);
It is call to createTheme. (i changed the m to lower case now so dont take it as an error)

Comment: @TT is it the default export, by any chance?

Comment: nope, the theme is default export

Comment: @TT - see the edited answer - your problem is ultimately because of `MainTheme`, in some way

Comment: Well i repaired the error with the 800 thing but now its has problem with primary. I added my theme up there.

Comment: @TT how accurate is your code? I see no call to createTheme in your file.

Comment: @TT in addition to all this, however, mui has specific instructions on how to be integrated to work with nextjs - have you followed them? https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-next-ts

Comment: I have my createTheme in _app file